# how to save bluetooth scan results in array of string?

Tags: android, bluetooth, network-scan

i know i can grab results of b.t scan to an arraylist like this code:

```
// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
};
// Register the BroadcastReceiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
```

but i want to use the results later, like putting them on a string array or something like this
can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, just make a static array/list somewhere and fill it and read it where ever you want. Only limit: Does not save the data over application restart. For that you should check database and/or SharedPreferences

Comment: i tryed like doing a for loop and every time putting the result into an array[] but the app will stuck. can you show me an example?